# Digital Sales and Tax Deductions

Tags: taxes, tax-deduction

If a company takes money from your sale, for example 30% in some cases, could you claim that as a loss on the sale?  I'd like to use a medium to sell a product but 30% is crazy!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is business finance, not personal finance.

Comment: This question applies to crafters and hobbyists and collectors who sell items online.  I think we need OP to clarify the POV from which "your sale" is evaluated.  @Thebluefish's answer, below, describes how to treat this as an expense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "loss on the sale" you mean "an expense", then yes that is fine.

Say you sell a $20 game on Steam (30% is very common on markets like Steam, Google Play Store, iTunes Store, etc...), then you would report:

- $20 as Income
- $6 as Expenses

Side note: 30% is actually not that bad. For a product I helped bring into a few retail store chains, they are effectively taking closer to 40%, though retail can vary depending on several factors.

Comment: Note that it is _not_ $14 income/$6 expenses. That would be double-counting the expense and result in your underpaying taxes.

Comment: I don't think it matters, but I think you would just report $14 as income. You don't actually ever receive, and were never owed, the $20. Steam simply paid you $14 for the sale.